# SELECT output of two views: second view blocked by UPDATE but returns successfully?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

In a SQL Server database, I have two tables, s and t. A further link table joins the two. THe relationship is one s to many t.

I have the following issue (In order of operation:)

1. An update stored procedure starts on table t.
2. A select by id stored procedure starts that selects from a view on table t and a view on table s.

The rows updated in table t are NOT linked to the Ids in table s that (2) is querying.

Both SPs take longer than expected to finish, implying some resource contention. (2) finishes before (1) completes, but only seems to return data from with view on s, not t. Finally, (1) finishes successfully. No deadlocks are reported - I have handling in place for these based upon SQL exception number.

Any thoughts? I think maybe the lock acquired by (1) stops (2) accessing the view on t, yet (2) finishes before (1)!

Comment: Just curious - why do you have a link table for a 1:n relationship? Wouldn't a simple foreign key from t to s suffice?

Comment: This is so general that I can only advise supplying the code and table definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses.

As it turns out a deadlock WAS occurring! However the stored proc returns 2 views, of which only the 2nd deadlocks. The `SqlCommand` returns these views into a `SqlDataReader`, which is read using a generic method with a passed in datareader method delegate.

Unfortunately, a bug in the `SqlDataReader` class (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316667) stopped the deadlock exception from propagating and therefore the operation was not retried.

I've worked around this by using a `DataAdapter` class to fill a `DataSet`, instead of the `SqlDataReader`. The deadlock excpetion is now thrown and can be retried successfully.

Answer (score 0):

What is your transaction isolation level set as?  What are the indexes on your tables?  When you do a `SELECT` on a table, the optimizer could be using an index.  When you do an `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`, the database engine needs to maintain that index which will lead to performance overhead.

Can you post your execution plans?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're using a transaction isolation level that allows dirty reads.  To find the default isolation level for the database, you can run "DBCC useroptions" in that database.  This tells you the isolation level for the database, but bear in mind that each process can set an isolation level, so review your procedure to see if an isolation level is being used for that one query.  Watch out for READ UNCOMITTED, which allows"dirty reads", a negative side effect of reading data without considering other transactions.

Also bear in mind that query hints like NOLOCK will also allow dirty reads.

More about isolation levels can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx

Best of luck!